# How can we define "trivially orthogonal" groups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, order-theory, lattice-orders

In any lattice-ordered group, we say that two elements are *orthogonal* if their meet is 1. I've been thinking of groups who have only "trivial" orthogonal relations, i.e. $x\perp y\implies x=1$ or $y=1$.

My first thought is that these are the totally ordered groups, but this is sufficient yet not necessary.

Next I thought that maybe these are the Archimedian groups. But $\mathbb Z^2$ lexically ordered has this property and is clearly non-Archimedian.

So I'm wondering:

1. Is there a more common name for this than "trivially orthogonal"?
2. Is there an alternative classification of these groups, or can we say anything interesting about them?

Comment: Isn't $ \mathbb Q[x]$ totally ordered lexically?

Comment: @PVAL: good point, I was thinking of an esoteric ordering. I have removed it for clarity.